# Values from 2 vectors that have same index

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I have 2 vectors vecA and vecB and they both store 100 randomly generated numbers between 0 and 999.
How can i extract the values from vecA that have same index with values of vecB and are greater than 780.

Answer (score 0):

Create a logical vector with `vecB` and use that to subset 'vecA' as the lengths are the same

```
vecA[vecB > 780]
```